# Planck constant: photon energy level and density question

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, dimensional-analysis, units

$$E = hf = \frac {hc}{\lambda} = J = eV$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt) says a photon with $\lambda = 532$ nm would have $E = 2.33$ eV $= 2.33$ J.

This calculates for a single photon, so is photon density required to calculate the energy for cross sectional area?  How is that found?

I see Planck's Law $B(f,T) = \frac P {m^3} = \frac {W} {t m^3}$ so perhaps $\frac W {m^3} =B(f, T) t$?

Comment: $1\,\mathrm{eV} = 1.60218\times10^{-19}\,\mathrm{J}$

Comment: This is intended as some friendly advice to help improve your question. Your question has a few equations and numbers, and some speculations; the title is not of the form of a question. It seems that what you want to know is how to calculate "the energy for cross sectional area." I think it would help if you added some more details about this. What cross-sectional area are you looking at? What do you want to know about the energy -- are you asking how much energy is crossing this cross-sectional area per unit time? What do you know about the photons -- are they in a bath with some temperature?

Comment: Also keep in mind that questions here should ask about a general concept, and not a specific problem -- "How do I apply this concept", rather than "how do I solve problem X?" There's some advice here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your question is incomplete.
You currently have the energy for each photon, $E_{\text{photon}}=hf$. If you we are provided other parameters we can assist you in reaching a conclusion.

For instance, if given "$10^{10}$ photons per square meter" then the energy density ($N_{\text{photons}} E_{\text{photon}}/A$) can be calculated as $10^{10} \text{photons} \cdot 2.33\frac{\text{eV}}{\text{photon}}/1\text{m}^2$.